# Why does manipulating LinkedList node alias allow this method to work?

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I don't understand why the method below works. As its name suggests, it removes all the null values in a Linked List, with the front of the list called `head`. I understand that an alias of the `head` variable is created with `Node<E> current = head`, but I can't figure out how this method manages to maintain the original head variable. By the looks of it, current is made smaller and smaller with each iteration (`current = current.next` or `current.next = current.next.next`), but somehow, a fully intact and accurate `head` variable remains when the Linked List is printed out. I'm sure this answer must be very simple, but it eludes me.

```
public void remove_nulls() {
    while (head!=null && head.data==null) {
        removeFirst();
    }
    if (head==null) {
        return;
    }
    // List is non-empty and does not start with a null item
    Node<E> current=head;
    while (current.next!=null) {
        if (current.next.data==null) {
            current.next=current.next.next;
            size--;
        } else {
            current = current.next;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: more information is required about the head variable. is it maintaining a deep copy?

Comment: @YogeshKaushik No, I don't believe so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that an alias of the head variable is created with
>   `Node<E> current = head`

This statement is not correct because `current` is not an 'alias', it's a new reference that points to the same address as `head`. So when you reassign `current = current.next` the `head` reference doesn't change, it will still point to the address it was pointing to, and `current` will point to the next element.

In other words, if the first element of the list is not `null`, the `head` reference will not be changed and will still point to the same element when the method completes. All other `null` elements are removed by this line: `current.next = current.next.next;`:

[image]

Comment: So then, how is the head variable ever modified? After this method completes, those changes are reflected in the list.

Comment: @TheFiveHundredYears you mean how the head element of the list gets modified? I think it happens in the `removeFirst()` method.

Comment: That's only executed if the first element's data is null

Comment: @TheFiveHundredYears correct, and if the first element's data is not null, it shouldn't be modified, right?

Comment: No, the method removes ALL nulls, so a middle element that is null would be removed.

Comment: @TheFiveHundredYears right, but the middle elements have nothing to do with the `head` reference. If the first element is not null, then `head` will still point to it. Removing of the middle elements is done by this line: `current.next=current.next.next;`

Comment: Okay, I think I finally understand it now! Thank you so much for your replies.

Comment: @TheFiveHundredYears no problem, I was glad to help