# Why are current and head references not considered aliases of each other in LinkedList implementation?

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

Consider the following addToBack method in the Linked List class

```
public void addToBack(int data) {
    Node newNode = new Node(data);
    if (head == null) {
        head = newNode; 
    }
    else {
        Node curr = head; //this is what I'm hung up on
        while (curr.next != null) {
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        curr.next = newNode;
    }
}
```

Why are current and head not aliases here? I thought that if two references point to the same object, then they are aliases and altering the contents of one will alter the other as well. So when assigned head to current, and reassigning current to current.next in the while loop, how come head is not also altered?

btw, I saw a similar question answered here: [Why does manipulating LinkedList node alias allow this method to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58175131/why-does-manipulating-linkedlist-node-alias-allow-this-method-to-work) , but don't understand the explanation as to WHY head and current and NOT aliases.

Comment: But you're reassigning a different value to `curr`, which means you're no longer making it point to the same object, so they're no longer "aliases"

Comment: Ah, I see. What if I did something like curr.data = 5 right after Node curr = head;, then would head and curr be aliases? and thus cause head.data to also become 5?

Comment: Yes, because `curr` and `head` still point to the same object by that point.